# What is src/blocks/checkpoints.dat and why is it not plaintext in the source code?

Tags: source

What is src/blocks/checkpoints.dat and why is it not plaintext in the source code?

In the source code src/blocks for Lithium Luna I see checkpoints.dat but it is not plaintext. I was under the impression that all source code should be human readable.

Can someone explain what this file is and what scenarios result in non-plaintext files in source code? Many thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the set of block hashes from the genesis block to a fairly recent block, and is used to speed sync up for historical blocks. It is typically updated shortly before a [new release](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/docs/RELEASE_CHECKLIST.md).

Those hashes are stored as is so they can be read without having to parse hex strings, which would be slower and use more memory.

To calculate `checkpoints.dat` for yourself, sync the blockchain past the latest checkpoint height (For example, height 2606000 for [release v0.17.3.2](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/6e1549cd778d7f23868432ca9a32516af9986a82/src/checkpoints/checkpoints.cpp#L252)). Then run the following commands to generate a list of block hashes:

```
monero-blockchain-export --block-stop <aforementioned height> --blocksdat --output-file mycheckpoints.dat
```

You can compare the generated file against the `checkpoints.dat` in the source tree:

```
diff mycheckpoints.dat /path_to_monero_repo/src/blocks/checkpoints.dat
```

You may have noticed the value `expected_block_hashes_hash` in the "Release Checklist" document. This is a simple SHA-256 digest of `checkpoints.dat`. This value should be equal to the value of:

```
sha256sum src/blocks/checkpoints.dat
```

This value is used to double-check the integrity of the `checkpoints.dat` file.

Comment: I see, thanks User36303. Easily readable with a hex editor. I'm surprised gedit doesn't read hex but apparently so.